# How to collect system calls from a binary with static analysis?

Tags: operating-system, reverse-engineering, system-calls, static-analysis

I would like to obtain a list of the system calls used in a given binary (x86_64) with static analysis. I tried strace but it does not guarantee that it is a complete list as some system calls might not be called during execution.

Comment: Would not the external link table suffice?

Comment: I don't really know what an external link table is but I will definitely look into that. Thanks!

Comment: The symbol table (AKA link table or dependency table) is a list of symbols in another binary module that is used by your program. When the OS loads your executable it resolves these dependencies by also loading the other module and connecting them. The way this works varies, but all COFF/PE files contain this table.

Comment: I see so it might only contain functions called in the binary but what I'm looking for is specific system calls. But getting a list of functions also helps as I can analyze those functions and find system calls which are called. I was wondering if there is a better and faster way to achieve that.

Comment: Removing system calls that are not called during execution would require solving the halting problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen He didn't say he was doing that. He just wants a list of all system calls that the program uses in any branch. The symbol table will give him that.

Comment: @hckuo2 The symbol table is what you want. It lists all dependencies, including dependencies on system modules. For example, on Windows, you will see dependencies on kernel32.dll. All the functions listed in the symbol table linking with kernel32.dll will be functions used by your program. Linkers are pretty good at not listing symbols not needed by your program, so the list you get will be pretty accurate.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I was misled by "it does not guarantee that it is a complete list as some system calls might not be called during execution." To me it sounds like OP wants system calls that are not called during execution to be trimmed from the list.

Comment: @RaymondChen It happens. OP adds unnecessary information about what he has already tried (“but [strace] does not guarantee ... a complete list”) which is subordinate to what he wants (“I would like to obtain a list of [all] system calls”). Reworded, it is: ‘I want a list of system calls used by <executable> but strace can’t give me that (because of the halting problem).’

Comment: @Dúthomhas Ah, I see how I misinterpreted the question. Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: @RaymondChen LOL, no problem. I do it all the time myself.

Comment: By that I mean some system calls might only be called during some rare cases instead of normal execution.

Answer (score 2):

For C/C++ you can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) to detect all the dependencies with the external libraries and system calls. However you have to analyse the source code and not the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

In static analysis, assuming that the binary is not obfuscated, there are several tools that could provide insight into the binary. The most commonly used is [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/). When analyzing the binary by itself, several compiling options play an important role in challenging static analysis techniques, namely dynamic vs static linked, stripped binary, optimization options, and etc.

One way of finding system calls is to use [IDAPython API](https://github.com/idapython/) to create a script in order to find system calls according to the descriptions here [X86 Assembly/Interfacing with Linux](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux) and here [Linux Syscall Reference](https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/). IDAPython provides a "good enough" API to look at the instructions in each Basic Block to conclude what system call is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

With the tool NDepend, you can do that with a code query, but only on .NET assemblies:

```
from x in ThirdParty.CodeElements
select new { x, callers = 
  x.IsMethod ? x.AsMethod.MethodsCallingMe.Cast<ICodeElement>() : 
  x.IsType   ? x.AsType.TypesUsingMe.Cast<ICodeElement>() : new ICodeElement[0] }
```

[image: NDepend calls to system]

Comment: Actually, I'm focusing on a compiled program like C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think the earlier answers are the simplest way to approach this. An option is to use a static analysis tool that supports binaries and navigate the control flow graph. That may allow you to exclude some functions if they are called in dead-code, but it would also be a lot more complex. GrammaTech CodeSonar is a commercial tool that supports binaries and may be able to help here.